# Jest cannot find file names with brackets in path

Tags: next.js, jestjs

I am currently trying to run some jest tests and jest cannot find my tests that have brackets in the path. I'm using Next.js which supports dynamic routing using brackets in file paths.

For example, my test's file path:
pages/projects/[group]/[project]/MyTest.test.tsx
Is not being found.

In jest.config.js, I'm using testMatch:

```
testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(test).ts?(x)']
```

This should be able to find the example path, but it's not. I've tried to use more explicit strings and escaping the brackets but nothing works.

Comment: What about `'<rootDir>/**/*.test.{ts,tsx}'`?